# how to hide original dropdown list in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to use select2 for my dropdown list. The options are from a database query. What I got is there are two dropdown lists showing. The first one is the original dropdown and the second is using select2.

The select code is:

```
     <select name="city" id="select-city" class="form-control">
        <option></option>
        <?php foreach ($cities as $ct) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $ct->id ?>"><?php echo $ct->name ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
```

And the javascript is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select-city").select2();
});
</script>
```

I want to hide the original dropdown. How can I do this?

Comment: Not really a helpful comment, but Select2 hides it automatically or at least it should. Maybe your CSS has something that overrides Select2's CSS?

Comment: I don't know. I call the select2 css link to the very last in the <head> but it's still not working

Comment: The order in which CSS files are loaded isn't always enough. If your own CSS files have lines with `!important` or more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules they will override the Select2's own CSS.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that you can easily see the element's CSS with the dev tools in Firefox or Chrome. Just inspect the element and check the CSS.

Comment: @Sevanteri, yes you're right. It's supposed to be hidden automatically. I should find which is overriding. Thanks